# Pass query param to custom page

Tags: customization, pages, urls

I had to create custom .php file that representing one page on my website.

I did it by creating new page in admin panel, and then renaming my .php file to page-customslug.php (where customslug is slug value of created page).

This works fine, and I can access my custom file via www.mydomain.com/customslug

What troubles me, is sending GET params to this page, like www.mydomain.com/customslug?par=1.

In this case I receive 404 Page not found.

Any suggestions why is this happening?
Thanks!

Comment: do your permalink settings have a trailing slash? typically it should be `/customslug/?par=1`

Comment: yes, I tried with trailing slash also, but with no luck. It's still 404

Comment: is the parameter you are trying to pass literally `par`, or is that just an example?

Comment: well, this is embarassing. My parameter name was 'day', and it is obviosly 'reserved' name. I changed it, and it works now. Thank you for helping, and sorry for my inadvertence!

Answer (score -1):

Do you enable any plug with function filter URL (Better WP Security,....)?

Yesterday I had a same problem, mine didn't pass parameters to progress. I disabled option filter URL, It worked.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey, no I don't have any plugin enabled, I just started creating website, so that's not the reason :)